# Simulate a MouseEvent

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I'd like to simulate a Mouse click on a Graphic. I added a Mouselistener, and some action when the mouseclick is done, but I really need to simulate that the user clicked on my Graphic in my programm... How can I say something like "" MouseEvent e is performed!"" ?

Actually I'd like to clean a "Graphics 2D canvas" when you click on a Jbutton called "Clean". But the thing is that the cleaning action would be done only if the user click on my "Graphics 2D canvas". I'd like to make the illusion that the "Graphics 2D canvas" was cleaned by clicking on the JButton..

Thanks.

```
     addMouseListener(this);
     addMouseMotionListener(this);
```

---

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            e.consume();
            x1=e.getX();
            y1=e.getY();
            if(figure==1 || figure==3 )   {x2=x1; y2=y1;}
            ;   }
```

PS : I can't use robot because I have to run my programm on every OS, and someone told me I can't run this on every programm :

```
Robot robot = null;
try {
    robot = new Robot();
} catch (AWTException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

 // SET THE MOUSE X Y POSITION
 robot.mouseMove(65*Fond_noir.pourcent_largeur, 16*Fond_noir.pourcent_hauteur);
 robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
 robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

}
```

Comment: On every OS :S I did it with a Robot, but I can't use it because it's only on Windows..

Comment: *"I did it with a Robot, but I can't use it because it's only on Windows"* - Sorry, that doesn't make sense, `Robot` is cross platform?

Comment: Yes because I did this (I edit my post)

Comment: Do you have to simulate a click on your own application, like using Mock; or do you need to simulate the click event that is being consumed by another application, which you can't control?

Comment: And moving the mouse of the user to perform a click is too dangerous :/ I'd like to programmly say, "action performed", and not perform the click by myself

Comment: I have to simulate that a click has been performed on my own application to perform the action of the MouseListener

Comment: Can't you just call the mousePressed method directly? It is just like any other Java method...

Comment: Yes for sure, but with this method I have to say where the mouse is pressed. I have a mouselistener on a specific Graphic. Moving the mouse to the graphic, then press it on the graphic, then going back to the initial position is too complicated; moreover, if the user maximizes my window the position of my graphic isn't the same, and it would click somewhere else and not on my graphic ..

Comment: Clarify your Question: What is the class of the Component you want to click? e.g. `JButton` has a doClick() method for this scenario. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28%29

Comment: It's a "Graphics 2D component" extended on a canvas. (Sorry it's not my programm, the developper before me created it's own canvas and method... )

Comment: Is there anyway I could say to my listener "MouseEvent e is performed!" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're right about Robot. It's platform dependent, and there are no guarantees that it will support all features on all platforms, from the JavaDoc:

> Note that some platforms require special privileges or extensions to
>   access low-level input control. If the current platform configuration
>   does not allow input control, an AWTException will be thrown when
>   trying to construct Robot objects. For example, X-Window systems will
>   throw the exception if the XTEST 2.2 standard extension is not
>   supported (or not enabled) by the X server.

To simulate the click, you can simply do this:

```
JButton buttonToSimulateClicking = new JButton(...);
buttonToSimulateClicking.doClick(); // As simple as that !
```

If you have to simulate the click "the hard way", i.e. to simulate a mouse click, you can always do the following:

```
MouseEvent clickEvent = new MouseEvent(buttonToSimulateClicking, MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, ...);

EventQueue eventQueue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();
eventQueue.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :) I have to use the "hard way" because I don't have to click on the JButton (the user does it) but I have to perform the click of my MouseListener listening on my Graphics 2D. I'm going to work with your second idea, i'd come back to tell you how it works.

Comment: When I use the line _"The method dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) from the type EventQueue is not visible"_ it says that the method dispatchevent is not visible... what does it mean?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Use `EventQueue`'s method `postEvent(...)` instead.

Comment: It means that the `dispatchEvent(...)` method has protected access.