# Trigger a `MouseEvent e` for JUnit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mouseevent

I am new to testing and am trying to work on a simple JUnit exercise which has a GUI and MainProgram.In the Main Program I have functions that are taking mouse event as a parameter and then changing the state of some variables based on the mouse event. Below is a example function.

```
abc(MouseEvent e) { //change some values }
```

I am trying to write a test case to simulate the mouse event e to be able to assert the changes made by the function.

I know this may sound really dumb to many of you but I would really like to learn how could I possible simulate the mouse event to be able to test if the function is working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the code within the mouse event to a separate methods and write a unit test for that method.

Comment: I get what you are suggesting but then this would just be a quick fix for the problem and won't help me in the long term.

If in the future there is any changes to these functions then my test cases written for all these functions would stand useless unless I manually make the changes to them.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864439/simulate-a-mouseevent?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @KhushalJobanputra You are making a strong argument why you **should** redesign your whole application. You **absolutely** want to **decouple** your "business logic" (the objects that have state, and "behavior" from the **representation. And yes, that is the whole point of unit tests: they test the **public contract** of your classes. So when that contract changes, you have to adapt your tests. And in your case, you probably want a class that translates mouse events into something else. But both ... what goes in, and what comes out, should not require a real GUI running.

Comment: Thanks for you responses guys. I found a solution to my problem. What I did was I hard coded a function which created a mouse event and there was a way to have actions on the mouse event and then I simply returned the mouse event. I then used the function in `abc(mouseevent)` this way.

The function that I created was 
`public MouseEvent click() {
MouseEvent mouseevent = new MouseEvent(/*passed the parameters for the mouse event here*/);`